# Should tense agree with reality first or preceding tense choice?

Tags: grammar, sequence-of-tenses

The title was a bit of a meta-question. I mostly just wanted to ask about the tense choice 'was(in bold in the following dialogue)' by Jake's Dad in a clip from Brooklyn 99 S07E10 6:12-6:20

> Jake's Dad: What the hell is my father doing here?
>
> Jake: You said you wanted to reconcile.
>
> Jake's Dad: I meant after he **was** dead. I planned on standing on his grave and yelling, ''I forgive you.''

I know Jake's Dad was probably thinking about the whole thing of him telling Jake about his wish to reconcile as a past event. But considering his father(Jake's grandfather) is still alive as he is complaining about him being in his house, wouldn't
*he was dead* sound a bit weird since he is still alive?

My native language doesn't inflect verbs to convey the concept of tense. We use more explicit adverbs of time to indicate when an action takes place.

So I get confused a lot in situations like this where some verb tenses(like 'was') when made to agree with the general tense choice for describing a past event may run counter to the reality(his father still being alive).

Is it a general rule of thumb to just keep the tenses all in the past in situations like this? Would using 'is' instead of 'was' be considered ungrammatical?

Comment: "I plan to stand on his grave after he is dead." "I planned to stand on his grave after he was dead."

Comment: Either would be acceptable here. "I meant after he's dead" is idiomatic (ie acceptable) (in informal speech, at least) although grammatically dubious. "I meant after he was dead" is another idiomatic way of saying informally "I meant after he has died".

Comment: Oh I guess my issue with 'was' is that I mistook 'he was dead' to mean 'he passed away at some point in the past' when there is actually an 'after' which makes it a conditional clause so 'after he was dead' is not saying that he already passed away but speaking to Jake's Dad posing a condition on his reconciliation, this act of conditioning, happens before him talking about it, naturally, thus the past tense 'was'... Would that make sense?

Comment: It's [backshifting](https://www.thoughtco.com/backshift-sequence-of-tense-rule-in-grammar-1689017). *I mean after he is dead.* --> *I meant after he was dead.*